# Mixing int and float in Halide

Tags: halide

I'm using Halide with VS2013. I've successfully built and run the first tutorial.

I'm trying to implement some of my code and do not understand why it won't compile. The code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

ImageParam input(UInt(8), 3);

Func input_clamped = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input);
Var x, y, c;

Func float_input_clamped;
float_input_clamped(x, y, c) = cast<float>(input_clamped(x, y, c)) / 255.0f;

Func input_lum;
input_lum(x, y) = cast<float>(0.299f * float_input_clamped(x, y, 0) + 0.587f * float_input_clamped(x, y, 1) + 0.114f * float_input_clamped(x, y, 2));

Func m45;
m45(x, y) = fabsf(input_lum(x - 1, y) - input_lum(x, y + 1)) + fabsf(input_lum(x, y + 1) - input_lum(x + 1, y + 2));

return 0;
}
```

The error occurs in the m45(x, y) = ... line. Apparently, input_lum isn't considered a float value. The error message is that "no suitable conversion from Halide::Expr to float exists."

Apparently all of the casts and float math are just being ignored.

(I know I don't initialize the input yet -- I'm trying to understand the way to think when I write Halide code, and the type inferencing is giving me fits.)

What am I doing wrong here?

(If it's not clear, I just want to take the luminance of a RGB image, and do some math on the luminance. I'd be delighted to stay in integer space if that works.)

OK, I experimented and tried this:

```
ImageParam input(UInt(8), 3);

Func input_clamped = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input);
Var x, y, c;

Func input_lum;
input_lum(x, y) = 0.299f * input_clamped(x, y, 0) + 0.587f * input_clamped(x, y, 1) + 0.114f * input_clamped(x, y, 2);

Func m45;
m45(x, y) = abs(input_lum(x - 1, y) - input_lum(x, y + 1)) + abs(input_lum(x, y + 1) - input_lum(x + 1, y + 2));
```

Now that compiles, but I have no idea what it is doing. Why wouldn't the type of input_lum() be float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion here is not mixing `int` and `float` expressions in your Halide code, but mixing `Halide::Expr`s with C++ `int` and `float` functions. `fabsf` is a C function which takes and returns C float values. What you actually want is a Halide intrinsic function which takes the absolute value of a Halide expression with floating point type. In this case, I believe that's `Halide::abs`, as you discovered in your second snippet.

The distinction between *compile/construction time* of your Halide program, which is run-time of this C++ code, and run-time of your Halide program (when you call `realize` or call into the function generated by `compile_to_file`), is a very common early stumbling block. If for the moment you remove any `using namespace Halide` it should be much clearer where you're explicitly using Halide functions like `Halide::abs`—actual standard C functions like `::fabsf` don't know anything about `Halide::Expr`s (the type you work with when you write Halide algorithm code), so you can never meaningfully use them in the way you were trying to in a Halide program. It just happens that many of the standard math functions in Halide have the same names as their `math.h` counterparts for convenience; without `using namespace Halide`, though, you'll be forced to be explicit about using the Halide functions (which make sense in this context), not the `math.h` or other functions (which don't).

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was fooled by fabsf() appearing in the list of available functions.